# variable 'error' referenced before assignmentRequest

Tags: python, django

In a Django application, I have some checks in a form which will return error = "something".
The thing is that that error will not be defined unless there is any error.

```
mycharacters = Character.objects.filter(username_id=request.user.id)

if(mycharacters.count() >= 5):
    error = True
if not error:
    #save to DB
```

The problem is that if there is no error, error variable will not exist.

I have also thought about a possibility in order to avoid this error, which would be:

```
error = None
#checks here
if error == None:
    #save to DB
```

But I am not sure whether this would be best approach.

Is there any way to do `if error var does not exist:` in Python?

Comment: Just a note from the PEP 8: `Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.`

Comment: There is a way of doing "if error var does not exist" in Python: you do `try: error; except NameError: …`. However, as the accepted answer shows, this is not the simplest solution to your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following:

```
error = mycharacters.count() >= 5
if not error:
    ...
```

**UPDATE**

```
error = mycharacters.count() >= 5
if error:
    to_json = {"incorrect":"Excedeed maximum"}
else:
    # Save to DB
```

Comment: What if I need to add an extra line below the `error = True`?

Comment: @Jerry, For example..?

Comment: Writing a an specific error like `to_json = {"incorrect":"Excedeed maximum"}`

Comment: Interesting two alternatives approaches, although I'll have to stick to mine as I have more than one thing to check. I guess that no other cleaner options are possible. Thanks @falsetru :)

Answer (score 1):

Either use an `else` branch:

```
if mycharacters.count() >= 5:
    error = True
else:
    error = False
```

or initialize the variable to the least likely value, and reassign:

```
error = False
if mycharacters.count() >= 5:
    error = True
```

The latter is often easier to read, but both approaches work (and so does the single-expression variant seen in other answers, even if that's harder to expand if you need to do more things).

(note that if you need to do more than just a simple assignment to establish the "false" value, the `if/else` construct usually wins, but in this case the cost of assigning twice is marginal.)

Checking if a variable exists can be done, but is verbose and bad programming style.  Missing variables should be considered programming errors, not hidden program state.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when your first condition (first if) gets failed then, that block won't execute hence there will not be any variable with name `error`, after that your second condition and there python interpreter doesn't get any variable with the name `error`, that is why it was giving the that `error` refereced before assignment.

```
mycharacters = Character.objects.filter(username_id=request.user.id)

if(mycharacters.count() >= 5):
    error = True
if not error:
    #save to DB
```

hence before `if(mycharacters.count() >= 5)` you can set a variable `error` with default value of `False` and set it to `True` only when the condition become true.